# Creating an object differences java

Tags: java, oop, object

I'm sure this question will have already been answered but I am not sure what the term for this is so what to search.

I am unsure of the difference between :

```
  JPanel a = new JPanel();
  a = new JPanel();
```

With the second line does a need to be declared as a variable at the top of the class?

Can somebody please attach a link where I can find out about this topic. I know this is very basic.

Comment: In the first line, you declare `a` as a `JPanel`, then assign it a new object. In the second line you only assign it a new object, and it needs to have been declared beforehand (as a `JPanel` or one of the classes / interfaces it extends).

Comment: Also, I find [Oracle's tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to be a good starting point

Comment: See @YCF_L answer, in other words, you cant initialize your object `a` by a `new` keyword without declaration. In Java, you have to declare type of your object (by JPanel a which means I want a object `a` of type JPanel) before Initialization.

Answer (score 12):

There are three cases : **Declaration**, **Initialization**, and (**Declaration, and Initialization**) :

This is the declaration of your Object:

```
JPanel a;
```

This Initialization of your Object :

```
a = new JPanel();
```

And you can make both of them in one step like you do :

```
JPanel a = new JPanel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand what is the strong typing language:

Java is strongly typed language

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing

> Java, Pascal, Ada and C require all variables to have a declared type, and support the use of explicit casts of arithmetic values to other arithmetic types. Java, C#, Ada and Pascal are sometimes said to be more strongly typed than C, a claim that is probably based on the fact that C supports more kinds of implicit conversions, and C also allows pointer values to be explicitly cast while Java and Pascal do not. Java itself may be considered more strongly typed than Pascal as manners of evading the static type system in Java are controlled by the Java virtual machine's type system. C# is similar to Java in that respect, though it allows disabling dynamic type checking by explicitly putting code segments in an "unsafe context". Pascal's type system has been described as "too strong", because the size of an array or string is part of its type, making some programming tasks very difficult